# How to distribute reading excel files task or process in multiple threads using c#

Tags: c#, excel, multithreading

I want to read excel files(more than 2  excel files with multiple worksheets ) by using  multiple threading and also I want to distribute  the reading process in these multiple threads.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what exactly do you mean by "read excel files"?

Comment: You won't get much unless your hardware can actually support parallel reads. Do you have RAIDed disks?

Comment: Reading excel files from particular location that part i have done, but I want the reading process should be done by multiple threads. Yeah i m also try to achieve that but didn't succeed

Comment: Not sure abt that @oleskii

Comment: @Rene: one thread for to read an excel files. I have created 4 threads then 4 threads should do the reading of 4 excel files. In this manner i want

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by *multiple threads*? Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

So you mean something like that:

```
public void StartFileLoading(string[] filenames)
{
    Task.WaitAll(filenames.Select(fn => Task.Run(() => ReadExcelFile(fn))).ToArray());
}
```

This creates a `Task` for each file to load and then waits for their completion (which you don't have to if you're not interested in the results).
You may want to add some error or result handling.

You can read the [docs about TaskFactory.StartNew](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew) for an alternative to `Task.Run` if you want to be more specific about how the tasks/threads should be created. But be sure that the framework knows best by itself most of the time.